# Tool to extract all requests being served at a point in time?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, logging

We are using Apache using the following log file format:

```
%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %D
```

Now we want to check which requests were being served by Apache at a given point in time. Is there any tool around, which can already do that using the timestamp and duration saved in the Apache log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that you will find a tool that can do that since `%D` is not a standard part of the default Apache logfiles.

It shouldn't be more than ten minutes work to write a script that would parse your logfiles and calculate the end time of each request and plot them all on a chart.

The whole exercise will only be worthwhile if your durations are over one million microseconds since the timestamp only has precision to the nearest second.

Comment: I hoped that there is already some tool, with a graphical interface showing the time line of all requests.